# Simplest approach to a dynamic where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

I'm hitting information overload when it comes to generating dynamic where clauses in EF. Some of the solutions look to be very dated (I'm targeting .NET 4.5 with EF 5).

Here's what I have:

```
public enum PersonTypes
{
    Lazy = 1,
    Awesome = 2,
    SuperHero = 3
}

public bool IncludeLazyPeople { get; set; }
public bool IncludeAwesomePeople { get; set; }
public bool IncludeSuperHeroPeople { get; set; }
```

Using EF I need to query for the people types that match the supplied bools.

I looked into this:
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

And this is what I came up with:

```
// create an expression that would include none of the person types
var personTypeExpression = PredicateBuilder.False<DAL.Models.Person>();

if (IncludeLazyPeople)
    personTypeExpression = personTypeExpression.Or(person => person.PersonType == (int)PersonTypes.Lazy);

if (IncludeAwesomePeople)
    personTypeExpression = personTypeExpression.Or(person => person.PersonType == (int)PersonTypes.Awesome);

if (IncludeSuperHeroPeople)
    personTypeExpression = personTypeExpression.Or(person => person.PersonType == (int)PersonTypes.SuperHero);

// filter the people for all included types
var filteredPeople = ctx.People.Where(personTypeExpression);
```

That failed to work because I didn't include the AsExpandable extension. Before I try that, I'm wondering if there is an easier approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person));
Expression personType = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(p, typeof(Person).GetProperty("PersonType"));
Expression personTypeExpression = Expression.Constant(false);
if (IncludeLazyPeople)
    personTypeExpression = Expression.OrElse(personTypeExpression, Expression.Equal(personType, Expression.Constant((int)PersonTypes.Lazy)));

//... same as above only with different Constant values

// filter the people for all included types
var filteredPeople = ctx.People.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<Person,bool>>(personTypeExpression,p));
```

This should do roughly what you'd want. Didn't check in compiler, hope not too many typos.

Comment: Just a missing closing parenthesis on the OrElse, otherwise it works great. :-)

Comment: @mbursill: also, I just noticed, you're targeting EF5, .net 4.5. Do you know you can have Enums instead of ints on your model then? in which case this code stays EXACTLY the same, just drop the `(int)`...

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = context.People.AsQueryable();

if (IncludeLazyPeople)
    query = query.Where(person => person.PersonType == (int)PersonTypes.Lazy);

if (IncludeAwesomePeople)
    query = query.Where(person => person.PersonType == (int)PersonTypes.Awesome);

if (IncludeSuperHeroPeople)
    query = query.Where(person => person.PersonType == (int)PersonTypes.SuperHero);
```

If you just need `AND` logic then you can call additional `Where()` methods on your query. Otherwise if you need a more powerful option then go with predicate builder or [System.Linq.Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx).

Comment: Woops, my example should have used OR instead of AND. I've updated the question. I'm looking into System.Linq.Expressions